# How far removed is the familial relationship between Darcon Leah and Tarsha Kaynin?

Tags: shannara, the-black-elfstone

In the Shannara series *The Defenders of Shannara*, we learned that Paxon Leah is a descendant of the Ohmsfords. While he didn't have the magic of the Wishsong, his sister did.

Now, Tarsha has the Wishsong, and we can surmise that the series takes place at least 200 years after *Defenders* (there's a mention of finding an artifact belonging to Arcannen over 200 years ago).

It's fair to make a connection that Dar and Tarsha have a familial connection. But how far removed is said connection?